# I have read that using the codeName of a sheet is the best way to refer to it. But aren't codeNames like global variables, and thus risky to use too?

Tags: vba

I actually ran into a problem when I unknowingly created a local variable (of type range) with the same name as an existing codeName. This happened because I had changed Sheet1's codeName to a descriptive one (the same as that of the local variable). Has anyone run into this problem? I spent an hour finding this logic error. One solution is to append every codeName with the word 'Sheet', but this goes against the "Clean Coding" principle of not including the object type in variable names. Is this an exception to this principle, since there is no risk of changing the type of the sheet object, and the reason "Clean Code" argues against including the object type in variable names is because of the risk of a developer changing the object type without changing the variable name?

Comment: Yes, an inner scope variable shadows an outer scope variable. Yes, we all have done it unknowingly at some point. No, it does not make code names any less useful. You can declare a variable named `Application`, which will shadow the global object `Application` which is Excel itself. Does it mean Excel should not exist or be used?

Comment: You can make this mistake in any programming language. Some modern IDE can have a code inspection that tells you when a local variable hides a global. The only static code analysis we have is https://rubberduckvba.com/

I think rubberduck can help you avoid this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for code names being the best way to refer to the sheet is because the average user doesn't know how to change them or are not even aware of the existence of them. They can and often do reindex or rename the sheets themselves though.

Globals are not risky to use, just don't abuse them. There are plenty of times when you need a global variable to do what you need to do. That is why most languages support them. I'm unsure of why so many people have a kneejerk reaction to globals.

You doubling up on a variable/codename is unfortunate but not a reason to never use codenames. People overwrite reserved keywords or built in functions but that doesn't mean we shouldn't use them.

The clean coding is subjective, be consistent. That is more important than whatever coding style you want to use.

Comment: Another reason to use code names, which I encountered recently, is if the sheet names are in different languages, characters of which are not supported by VBA editor. The names just appear as ??????. So without code names I would have lost a good contract.